# Web Scraping with python and scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap a site with this types of div:

```
<div class="mindatath">Density:</div>
<div class="mindatam2">
3.98 - 4.1 g/cm
<sup>3</sup>
(Measured)    3.997 g/cm
<sup>3</sup>
(Calculated)
</div>
</div>
```

Ok, I need the value in mindatam2 div. But exist a lot of divs with this class. How can I relate the two divs to I know what the value to extract?

I try with Scrapy to show all divs values:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="mindatam2"]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here, you want the first `div` with the class `mindatam2`?

Comment: No, I dont know the position div of "density". I want a way to discover how I know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your densities have similar format, you can use `regex`
For example
`response.xpath('//div[@class="mindatam2"]/text()').re(r'([\d\.\-\s]+)g/cm')`

Comment: Regex, is it! Thank you very much!